# Look for an array in the same column as a VLookUp value

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I have the following formula which identifies a value on another sheet (called "Mold") in my excel file via VLOOKUP, then tells me the position inside array "Mold!C17:C116" and consequently looks for the value inside "table1" taking into consideration the row position from the MATCH function and column 2 inside the INDEX function:

`INDEX(table1,MATCH(VLOOKUP($B$17,Mold!$B$5:$AZ$181,C$8+1,FALSE),Mold!C17:C116,0),2)`

The sheet I have this formula in changes the values according to a dropdown list (located in "C$8"). What I am trying to achieve is that the array "Mold!C17:C116" adjusts according to the column where the value of the VLOOKUP is found. For example, if the value is found in column X, tell me the position of it in the array located in the same column X17:X116, if value was found in column Y, look for position in array within the same column Y (rows 17 to 116 should always remain the same).
How can I make the array and VLOOKUP work together in the same column?

Thanks in advance for the help, and please let me know if something is not clear enough.

The formula presented above is what I´ve tried but it only works in one column, as I pull formulas to the right to other columns, it only looks for values in that one specific column and not in the same column as its VLOOKUP Value.

Comment: I would start with the following reading: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),
[Help Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking),
[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Apart from not showing us samples of data to show why you expect the formula to work with expected result. Have you tried checking the separately evaluate the lookup formulas? Also you're using table reference for INDEXING butnone of the lookups refer to the table. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct @P.b, none of the lookups belong to the table. I prepared a document to explain in a better way my issue but I can´t find how to upload it to my post.